# How to find 3 or more words in the same line and highlight only them instead of a whole text using grep?

Tags: regex, grep

I would like to find all lines where there are at least 3 words "the".

I know how to find these lines using regular expressions:

```
grep -E "(the)(\s(.+)\s\1){2,}" file.txt
```

It works, grep finds such lines. But my question is: **is it possible to highlight only the words "the" instead of the whole text between the first and last "the"?**

In other words, I don't want find all "the" words in the text but only those lines where there at least 3 "the" and highlight only those words to make it more readable.

I was trying to use something from https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html
like `(?=)` but it doesn't work:

```
grep -E "(the)((?=\s(.+)\s)\1){2,}" file.txt
```

Text:

```
the cat
in the garden there was the cat
in the box there is the cat and the dog and the bird
aaa the bbb the ccc the ddd
```

Current output:

```
in the box there is the cat and the dog and the bird
aaa the bbb the ccc the ddd
```

Desirable output:

```
in the box there is the cat and the dog and the bird
aaa the bbb the ccc the ddd
```

Comment: Try `grep -oP "(the)(?=(?:\s.+\s\1){2,})" file.txt`

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe one grep to another:

```
grep -E '(\bthe\b.*?){3}' file | grep --color '\bthe\b'
```

**Output:**

> in **the** box there is **the** cat and **the** dog and **the** bird
>    aaa **the** bbb **the** ccc **the** ddd`

1st `grep` find all the lines with at least 3 full words `the` and 2nd `grep` just colors each `the` word.

Comment: What if I want to find any 3-letter word (`[a-z]{3}`) instead of "the"?

Comment: Then you may use: `grep -E '(\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b.*?){3}' file | grep --color -E '\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\b'`

Comment: Did that help??

Answer (score 0):

Here is an awk that counts the words on each line and bolds the words whose count is three or more:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    b="\033[1m"
    n="\033[0m"
}
{
    delete a
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        # if(lenght($i)==3)  # uncomment this to consider three-letter words only
        a[$i]++
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        printf "%s%s%s%s",(a[$i]>=3?b:""),$i,(a[$i]>=3?n:""),$i==NF?ORS:OFS)
}' file
```

> the cat 
>  in the garden there was the cat
>   in **the** box there is **the** cat and **the** dog and **the** bird
>   aaa **the** bbb **the** ccc **the** ddd

If you want to consider three-letter words only, add `if(length($i)==3)` before `a[$i]++`.

**Edit:**

I missed the part to only print bolded lines. Now fixed:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    b="\033[1m"
    n="\033[0m"
}
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if(length($i)==3)
            a[$i]++
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
        buf=buf (i>1?OFS:"") (a[$i]>=3&&(f=1)?b:"") $i (a[$i]>=3?n:"")
    if(f)
        print buf
    delete a; buf=""; f=""
}' file
```

> in **the** box there is **the** cat and **the** dog and **the** bird
>   aaa **the** bbb **the** ccc **the** ddd